# logarithm and exponential, What does this assembly code do?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, exponential, fpu

What is the result of the following assembly code?

```
fld qword ptr [address2]
fld qword ptr [address1]
fldl2e
fmulp   ST(1),ST
fld ST(0)
frndint
fxch    ST(1)
fsub    ST,ST(1)
f2xm1
fld1
faddp   ST(1),ST
fscale
```

Here, I don't understand what this code is doing. What I have interpreted is as following:

`value[address2]^(2^(value[address1]*log2(e)-roundf(value[address1]*log2(e))))`

Which does not make sense. Could someone please correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time please post you attempted comments next to the disassembly.  It's taking a long time to type everything out to see if I end up at the same place as you.  Also, there's a whole [stackexchange for reverse engineering.](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)  I don't usually look at it, but there are some good x86 experts there.

let's say `v1 = contents of addr1` and `v2 = ... [addr2]`.

```
fld qword ptr [address2]   ; st(0) = v2
fld qword ptr [address1]   ; st(0) = v1, st(1) = v2
fldl2e                     ; st0 = l2e = log_2(e); st1=v1 st2=v2
fmulp   ST(1),ST           ; st0 = v1*l2e;  st2=v2
fld ST(0)                  ; st0 = v1*l2e; st1=v1*l2e  st2=v2
frndint                    ; st0 = round(v1*l2e); st1=v1*l2e  st2=v2
fxch    ST(1)              ; st0 = v1*l2e; st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
; careful here, this is fsub, NOT fsubp
fsub    ST,ST(1)           ; st0 = v1*l2e - round(v1*l2e) = fractional part of v1*l2e = v1l2efrac; st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
f2xm1                      ; st0 = 2^(v1l2efrac)-1; st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
fld1                       ; st0 = 1.0;  st1 = 2^(v1l2efrac)-1  st2=round(v1*l2e)  st3=v2
faddp   ST(1),ST           ; st0 = 1.0 + 2^(v1l2efrac)-1 = 2^v1l2efrac; st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
  ; st0 = 2^v1l2efrac; st1=round(v1*l2e);  st2=v2
fscale                 ; st0 = 2^v1l2efrac * 2^round(v1*l2e); st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
  ; st0 = 2^(v1l2efrac + round(v1*l2e));  st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
  ;  simplify: fractional part + integer part = whole
  ; st0 = 2^(v1*l2e);  st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2 
  ;  simplify: x^y = 2^(y * log2(x))
  ; st0 = e^v1;        st1=round(v1*l2e)  st2=v2
```

So in the end, `st(0) = e^[address1]`, with 2 other values still on the FP stack.  (The contents of the rest of the FP stack, and how deep it is, is a huge point which you left out of your analysis.  FP stack pushes and pops have to balance (except for leaving a return value in `st(0)`), so that can act as a check on whether you've correctly traced a piece of code.)

AFAICT, v2 is left on the FP stack at the end of this, and unused in the calculation.  It looks like you had 2 extra pops in your tracing.